# Throw PHP variable back to Ajax on submit form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay so I have an ajax function which sends data to `register-process.php`. I want the `register-process.php` to send the PHP value `$msg` back to ajax. I tried using `$('.message').html("<?php $msg; ?>").fadeIn(500);` on success but it does not seems to work. Is there any way to do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var email    = $("#email").val();
        var cpass    = $("#cpass").val();
        var dataString = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            cpass: $("#cpass").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
                $('.message').html("<?php $msg; ?>").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

register-process.php

```
<?php
include'config/db.php';
$msg = null;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$uname  = (!empty($_POST['username']))?$_POST['username']:null;
$pass   = (!empty($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:null;
$cpass  = (!empty($_POST['cpass']))?$_POST['cpass']:null;
$email  = (!empty($_POST['email']))?$_POST['email']:null;

if($_POST){
    $stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE mem_uname = :uname";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt-> bindValue(':uname', $uname);
    $stmt-> execute();
    $checkunm = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    $stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE mem_email = :email";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $checkeml = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if($uname == '' or $pass == '' or $cpass == '' or $email == ''){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Fields cannot be left empty. Please fill up all the fields.</div>";
    }else if($checkunm > 0){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>This username is already registered. Please use a different username.</div>";
    }else if($checkeml > 0){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>This Email ID is already registered. Please use a different Email ID.</div>";
    }else if($pass != $cpass){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Passwords are not matching.</div>";
    }else if(strlen($uname) > 12){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Username should not be more than 12 characters long.</div>";
    }else if(strlen($uname) < 6){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Username must be at least 6 characters long.</div>";
    }else if(strlen($pass) < 6){
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Password must be at least 6 characters long.</div>";
    }else{
        // If everything is ok, insert user into the database
        $stmt = "INSERT INTO members(mem_uname, mem_pass, mem_email)VALUES(:uname, :pass, :email)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
        $stmt-> bindValue(':uname', $uname);
        $stmt-> bindValue(':pass', password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
        $stmt-> bindValue(':email', $email);
        $stmt-> execute();

        if($meq){
            $msg = "<div class='message-success'>Congratulations! You have been registered successfully. You can now login!</div>";
        }else{
            $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Server Error! Please try again later. If problem persists, please contact support.</div>";
        }
    }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Ajax function no need to echo the php variable.Just map response to your html element like below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
                console.log(html);//see output on browser console
                $('.message').html(html).fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wow so easy.. Its working I only needed to put `html` inside the `.html`... great.. can you explain this a bit on how it works?

Comment: The response from server may be in `json`,`html`,`text`.. etc format.And once response is back then it is the part of js [not php] that defines how you need to handle response.In your case the response in in `html` format then in ajax success function just need to set `$(selector).html()` to map properly.